# How to install internet explorer with windows media player plugin via wine?

Tags: 10.10, wine, winetricks

I have installed internet explorer in Ubuntu 10.10 with the help of wine and winetricks.
However, when I play an audio file in Internet Explorer its not getting played. Instead, it shows a empty square box.

So, is it possible to install Windows Media Player via Wine?

If yes please help me with installation steps. So that i can play audio files in internet explorer. If not, is it possible to change the player of Internet Explorer so that the audio files will get played in another player?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Media Player can be installed using PlayOnLinux and (if I remember correctly) winetricks.

However, with the first solution, you would need to add Internet Explorer to the Wine prefix that PlayOnLinux used for Windows Media Player and run it from there.

Either way you do it, it may not work though, since both Internet Explorer and Windows Media Player work poorly at best in Wine. Furthermore, I don't think you can download Windows Media Player 9.x and previous versions any longer.

---

As for using another player in Internet Explorer, I've never actually tried that, but you could probably install DivX as your media player for Wine, since that does provide a browser plugin and will most likely automatically play your files.